# Possible to INSERT INTO from an IF statement

Tags: php, sql

Just wondering if it's possible to run a `INSERT INTO` sql command through an if statement?

I've got a few test groups that contain test members and I want to add the group id to a db table if the `group_id` equals `3`. I'm unsure how the `INSERT INTO` sql would be written.

I'm currently passing the `group_id` number into a variable called `$groupIDResult`.

The only code I have currently got is:

```
if ($groupIDResult[0] == 3) {}
```

Comment: Remember to mark an answer as accepted if you find one that works for you.

Comment: @JakeGould Sorry, that meant to say "I'm unsure how the if statement with INSERT INTO sql would be written. I've will mark your answer as accepted though as it now appears to be working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just wondering if it's possible to run a INSERT INTO sql command
>   through an if statement?

Yes. An `if` statement is just a condition that checks criteria you set such as whether `$groupIDResult[0]` is equal to `3`. So just do this and all is good:

```
if ($groupIDResult[0] == 3) {
   // INSERT INTO query & related PHP logic to run that query goes here.
}
```

But you state:

> I'm unsure how the INSERT INTO sql would be written.

So what is the real question? Is it about a SQL query or an `if` condition? Because you are on the right track but it’s unclear why you are having problems.

Answer (score 0):

The insert statement would go in your curly braces and would be of the form

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column_name) VALUES(your_value)
```

Consult the PHP manual or the manuals for any framework you're using for specific syntax.

W3Schools.com also has some intro to SQL material you may find useful.